# Integrating Frontend JavaScript Code with AES Encryption getting ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I'm currently working implementing AES encryption in the backend using Python, but I'm encountering some issues in ensuring compatibility between frontend and backedn. I need help in integrating the frontend JavaScript code to work with it.

My backend Python code:

```py
class Crypt():
    def pad(self, data):
        BLOCK_SIZE = 16
        length = BLOCK_SIZE - (len(data) % BLOCK_SIZE)
        return data + (chr(length)*length)

    def unpad(self, data):
        return data[:-(data[-1] if type(data[-1]) == int else ord(data[-1]))]

    def bytes_to_key(self, data, salt, output=48):
        assert len(salt) == 8, len(salt)
        data += salt
        key = sha256(data).digest()
        final_key = key
        while len(final_key) < output:
            key = sha256(key + data).digest()
            final_key += key
        return final_key[:output]

    def bytes_to_key_md5(self, data, salt, output=48):
        assert len(salt) == 8, len(salt)
        data += salt
        key = md5(data).digest()
        final_key = key
        while len(final_key) < output:
            key = md5(key + data).digest()
            final_key += key
        return final_key[:output]

    def encrypt(self, message):
        passphrase = "<secret passpharse value>".encode()
        salt = Random.new().read(8)
        key_iv = self.bytes_to_key_md5(passphrase, salt, 32+16)
        key = key_iv[:32]
        iv = key_iv[32:]
        aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(b"Salted__" + salt + aes.encrypt(self.pad(message).encode()))

    def decrypt(self, encrypted):
        passphrase ="<secret passpharse value>".encode()
        encrypted = base64.b64decode(encrypted)
        assert encrypted[0:8] == b"Salted__"
        salt = encrypted[8:16]
        key_iv = self.bytes_to_key_md5(passphrase, salt, 32+16)
        key = key_iv[:32]
        iv = key_iv[32:]
        aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self.unpad(aes.decrypt(encrypted[16:])).decode().strip('"')
    
    def base64_decoding(self, encoded):
        base64decode = base64.b64decode(encoded)
        return base64decode.decode()
    
crypt = Crypt()

test = "secret message to be send over network"

encrypted_message = crypt.encrypt(test)
print("Encryp msg:", encrypted_message)
decrypted_message = crypt.decrypt(encrypted_message)
print("Decryp:", decrypted_message)
```

here's what I've tried so far on the frontend with React and CryptoJS:

```js
import React from "react";
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const DecryptEncrypt = () => {
    function bytesToKey(passphrase, salt, output = 48) {
        if (salt.length !== 8) {
            throw new Error('Salt must be 8 characters long.');
        }

        let data = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(passphrase + salt);
        let key = CryptoJS.SHA256(data).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);
        let finalKey = key;

        while (finalKey.length < output) {
            data = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(key + passphrase + salt);
            key = CryptoJS.SHA256(data).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);
            finalKey += key;
        }

        return finalKey.slice(0, output);
    }

    const decryptData = (encryptedData, key) => {
        const decodedEncryptedData = atob(encryptedData);
        const salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(decodedEncryptedData.substring(8, 16));
        const ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(decodedEncryptedData.substring(16));
        const keyIv = bytesToKey(key, salt.toString(), 32 + 16);
        const keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyIv.substring(0, 32));
        const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyIv.substring(32));

        const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
            { ciphertext: ciphertext },
            keyBytes,
            { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 }
        );

        
        return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    };

    const encryptData = (data, key) => {
        const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(8); // Generate random salt
        const keyIv = bytesToKey(key, salt.toString(), 32 + 16);
        const keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyIv.substring(0, 32));
        const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyIv.substring(32));

        const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, keyBytes, {
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

        const ciphertext = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
        const saltedCiphertext = "Salted__" + salt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex) + ciphertext;

        return btoa(saltedCiphertext);
    };

    const dataToEncrypt = 'Data to be sent over network';
    const encryptionKey = "<secret passpharse value>";

    const encryptedData = encryptData(dataToEncrypt, encryptionKey);
    console.log("Encrypted data:", encryptedData);

    const decryptedData = decryptData(encryptedData, encryptionKey);
    console.log("Decrypted data:", decryptedData);

    return (<>
        Check
    </>);
}

export default DecryptEncrypt;
```

I'm encountering some issues in ensuring compatibility between frontend and backedn. Specifically, I'm struggling with properly deriving the key and IV, and encrypting/decrypting the data in a way that matches the backend implementation. Getting error as below when i try to send encrypted text to backend where it throws following error while decrypting,

```
packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 246, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Data must be padded to %d byte boundary in CBC mode" % self.block_size)
ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode
```

I m bit new to implementing AES in a fullstack app, so learning and trying but still stuck with this issue. Could someone who has encountered similar issue or implemented encryption/decryption in JavaScript offer some guidance or suggestions on how to modify my frontend code to achieve compatibility with the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier than you think.

The Python code performs an OpenSSL compliant encryption/decryption:

- The key derivation is `EVP_BytesToKey()` compatible. It uses MD5 as digest, an iteration count of 1 and an 8 bytes salt.
- As encryption/decryption AES-256 in CBC mode and PKCS#7 padding is applied.
- The result is returned in the Base64 encoded OpenSSL format. The OpenSSL format consists of the concatenation of the ASCII encoding of `Salted__`, followed by the 8 bytes of salt, followed by the actual ciphertext.

CryptoJS is OpenSSL compatible (s. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#interoperability)) and supports the above encryption/decryption by default. All you need to do is pass the passphrase as string (s. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input)).

Note that when using `bytes_to_key()` instead of `bytes_to_key_md5()` in the Python code, SHA256 must be explicitly specified as digest on the CryptoJS side, as MD5 is the default.

CryptoJS sample code:

```js
// MD5 sample

var ciphertextFromPython = "U2FsdGVkX18lJwVCQIbRWqiIycIZg4LRZFHq+ORvygkE/umH1Il3m/yzgu3n9jVQhUikwXeURBW9yAjMawTk3A==";
var passphrase = "<secret passpharse value>";
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextFromPython, passphrase);
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

var plaintext = "secret message to be send over network";
var passphrase = "<secret passpharse value>";
var ciphertextForPython = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, passphrase);
console.log(ciphertextForPython.toString()); // e.g. U2FsdGVkX18/aYM99XaqbT/GjFDAuNlGBMd2Wd7Vuum120DkmeItS7tJndPLbxDyNzEUBF28AOG5pOwLGvpSSA==

// SHA-256 sample

CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.cfg.hasher = CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create(); 

var ciphertextFromPython = "U2FsdGVkX189ft5ncnmOK/rJIB2fkdrfdWQCbf6DgbXkWMXw7yjX2oRXbDgZTIt4LibWBPamalnKCZl3l1VnWQ==";
var passphrase = "<secret passpharse value>";
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextFromPython, passphrase);
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

var plaintext = "secret message to be send over network";
var passphrase = "<secret passpharse value>";
var ciphertextForPython = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, passphrase);
console.log(ciphertextForPython.toString()); // e.g. U2FsdGVkX188W7G1Xis9KZogKpVCvCVbDQHc1AIul+CSTjS8m+zdc4pPQ9jlunIP4jbTD49q82GV9ic/4HVNNA==
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.2.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

In the CryptoJS code above, `ciphertextFromPython` was generated with the posted Python code and `ciphertextForPython` can be decrypted with the posted Python code.

The first example applies MD5 as digest (by default) and correponds to the key derivation function `bytes_to_key_md5()`, the second applies SHA256 (explicitly specified) and correponds to `bytes_to_key()`.

---

Security:

The key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()`, especially in combination with the broken digest MD5 and an iteration count of 1, is considered insecure. Instead, a reliable key derivation function should be applied (at least PBKDF2, which is also supported by CryptoJS).

Note that CryptoJS has been [discontinued](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js?tab=readme-ov-file#discontinued). The last version is 4.2.0.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and the helpful information. It worked like a charm!